# Processing parallel HTTP requests in batches in Node.js using async

Tags: node.js, httprequest, async.js, batching

I have code that is structured roughly as follows:

```
readLine.on('line', function (line) {
    async.parallel([
    function (callback) {
        // HTTP request #1 sent with accompanied JSON, get JSON as result
    },
    function (callback) {
        // HTTP request #2 sent with accompanied JSON, get JSON as result
    }],
    function (error, results) {
        // write to local file
    })
```

I implemented the input stream with `line-by-line` module.
My problem is that once my code has begin to run for 30 seconds or so, I get `ECONNREFUSED` and `ECONNRESET` errors, which I assume is because all my TCP connections are overloaded (all the HTTP requests go to a localhost server). It definitely doesn't help that the text file I have to read has about 200,000 lines.

Is there any way to process the lines and HTTP requests in batches and wait till all the requests have gone through and have returned successfully, so I don't overload my TCP sockets?
Thanks in advance for any help and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to use [`async.queue`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue), which has a configurable concurrency.

```
var queue = async.queue(function(task, queueCallback) {
  async.parallel([
  function (callback) {
    // HTTP request #1 sent with accompanied JSON, get JSON as result
  },
  function (callback) {
      // HTTP request #2 sent with accompanied JSON, get JSON as result
  }],
  function (error, results) {
    // write to local file
    ...
    // call the queue callback
    queueCallback(error);
  })
}, 10); // 10 concurrent 'tasks' max

readLine.on('line', function (line) {
  queue.push({ line : line });
});
```

Comment: I'll have to check whether this works when I get back to work tomorrow, but configurable concurrency definitely looks like what I've been searching for! Much appreciated.